# Module not found: Can't resolve './data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

There was an error using the swiper in Nextjs.

"next": "^12.0.3", "swiper": "^7.2.0"

I'm using the version and I want to know how to solve the issue.

Module not found: Can't resolve './data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved it by reading a few places on stackoverflow.

"swiper": "^6.8.4" downgrade to this version.
I was also getting an error in swiper css imports. I imported the scss modules in them and called them in _app.tsx.

[The code that made the compile problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re0u8.png)

I extracted the above code from scss and compiled it. Next module style construct does not compile base:64.